# How to tell which users are running which reports?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I apologize if this isnt the right domain. I searched all the stack exchange communities.

I'm using Microsoft PowerBI and would like to know which of the reports created are being run and by which users?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI has a built-in feature called **Usage Metrics**, which might meet your needs.  It is described on this page, but when you try it you'll find there's a new (undocumented) page provided called **Report list** that gives a summary view of all the reports in a Workspace.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-modern-usage-metrics

FYI that process also produces a Power BI dataset with the underlying data, and there are lots of blogs etc on building custom reports on that dataset or combining data for multiple Workspaces.

The non-Premium Power BI Admin feature on this topic is a relic - not very useful at all.